# How to keep a count of how many times a function which returns itself has been called?

Tags: javascript

My question is, if I have a function like this

```
function f(a) {
if (a == undefined) {
    alert(1)
    return f
} else {
    alert(2)
}
```

}

and I call it like this, for example, `f()()()()('123')`, how can I keep track of how many times f was called?

Edit:
I had a play around and worked out a solution:

```
function f(a) {
if (!f.count) {
    f.count = 0;
}
if (a == undefined) {
    alert(1);
    ++f.count;
    return f;
} else {
    f.count = 0;
    alert(2);
}
```

}

alert(1) and alert(2) are essentially placeholders for the moment. The count variable would be used in the else section in the actual function.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than pollute the global space, attach the counter to the function itself.

```
function f(a)
{
    ++f.counter;
    if (a) {
       doAThing();
       return f;
    } else 
       doAnotherThing();
}
f.counter = 0;
```

Now you can access the number of calls by evaluating f.counter at any point.

Comment: crazy javascript, interesting :)

Comment: While accessing like f()()()()('123') this gives an error

Comment: It might, I'm just illustrating how to write the counter as a static function member, not how to do the actual working guts.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a count variable outside of the function scope and whenever you enter the function, you increase its value.

```
var count = 0;

function f(a) {
    count++;

    if (!a) {
        alert(1);
        return f;
    } else {
        alert(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answers, don't just dump out code

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained more. I don't want the function to have a count variable with global scope. I want to be able to reuse the function. I tried using a wrapper function but couldn't get it to work

Comment: @SJC what do you mean with "reuse"? do you want to use it somewhere else?

Comment: @Basti bit of SO tip: never assume it's obvious, otherwise the question wouldn't exist

Comment: Yes, I meant that I wanted to be able to call the function elsewhere with the count variable always starting at zero.

Answer (score 0):

By "wrapper function) do you mean "closure"?

```
var f = (function (a) {
  var count = 0; 

  return function () { 
    console.log(count);
    count += 1;

    if (!a) {
      alert(1);
      return f;
    } else {
      alert(2);
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Why you are writting "if (!a) {
        alert(1);
        return f;
    } else {
        alert(2);
    }". Your cursor will never come here